# Reading and writing a serialized object in android

Tags: java, android, serialization

I've been searching on here but can't seem to find what works.  I'm trying to write a simple object list to a serialized file and can't seem to locate the file in android.  It's my first time building an app and I had this working in netbeans by pointing to src/list.ser, however, this doesn't work in android studio.  I guess my question is where do I place the ser file and how do I point to it in the code?  Here is my code:

ListActivity:

```
 public class ListActivity extends Activity implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Item> list;

    public List() throws Exception {
        list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    public void addItem(String name) {
        list.add(new Item(name));

    }

    public void addCurrentList() throws Exception{

        String pathToAppFolder = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
        String filePath = pathToAppFolder +File.separator + "list.ser";

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));



            os.writeObject(list);
            os.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("NOPE NOPE NOPE NOPE");


        }
    }



    public void addItem(String name, int price) {
        list.add(new Item(name, price));
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> populate() {
        return list;
    }
    public void record() {

        try {

            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/list.ser"));
            ArrayList<Item> list2 = (ArrayList<Item>) in.readObject();
            System.out.println(list2);
            list = list2;

            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    private List tester;
    private ListView lv;
    private EditText gg;
    private Button button;
    private Button clearButton;
    private ArrayList list;
    String pathToAppFolder = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
    String filePath = pathToAppFolder + File.separator + "list.ser";

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        try {
            tester.addCurrentList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //create the list

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDisplay);
        ListView mine = lv;
        list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            tester = new List();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }




        for (Item item : tester.populate()) {
            list.add(item);
        }

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        final TextView firstTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);

        gg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String no = gg.getText().toString();
                if (!no.isEmpty()) {
                    tester.addItem(no);
                    arrayAdapter.add(no);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    gg.setText("");

                }

            }
        });

        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                arrayAdapter.clear();
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(position));
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Printing a blank line is not an acceptable way to report an exception.Tell us what exception is thrown, when you find out.

Comment: I know, I just deleted it for this post because it contained some angry response.  I have something there that might be offensive to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure that you have permission to write to the external storage.

as,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can use,

```
  public void addCurrentList() throws Exception{

            String pathToAppFolder = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
            String filePath = pathToAppFolder +File.seperator + "list.ser";
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
                os.writeObject(list);
                os.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
```

and the use create a file path from that as,

```
String filePath = pathToAppFolder +File.seperator + "Test.text";
```

and then where ever you want to read this file again, you can recreate the path. Because you have access to the `context` from the android code

EDIT

You can not access the context as you do in your code. You can do it in your onCreate method. I have added only the necessary parts.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pathToAppFolder = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
        filePath = pathToAppFolder + File.separator + "list.ser";
        //create the list
```

Oh my god, I had to go into great lengths to answer your question. Here it is, Your List class is not an Activity in your application. It is just a class. So I suggest you to remove those inheritance first. remove this `extends Activity`. And I suggest you to change the List class name to something else. Because, `List` is a defined keyword and its not a best practice to do so.

Change the method in List Activity as below.

```
    public void addCurrentList(String filePath) throws Exception

            try {
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));



                os.writeObject(list);
                os.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());


            }
        }

public void record(String filePath) {

        try {

            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
            ArrayList<Item> list2 = (ArrayList<Item>) in.readObject();
            System.out.println(list2);
            list = list2;

            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

In your MainActivity, onDestroy Method,
change the code to,

```
tester.addCurrentList(filePath);
```

Comment: I tried using context before and it keeps saying symbol not found.  How do I use context?

Comment: try my edit, you can do the same with the reading of the file

Comment: Tried your edit, still throwing an exception.  Where do I place the .ser file?  Should it be in the assets folder?

Comment: This file will be created in your app folder (App folder is the location where it is dedicated to your application). Do you actually want to put an existing file rather than creating a new one. I guess the exception is file not found right?

Comment: It is giving me a null pointer exception now.  It says it's in the line where you put null.

Comment: Testing `exists()` and calling `createNewFile()` is pointless and wasteful here. `new FileOutputStream()` has to do that anyway, in the operating system. No sense in doing it twice.

Comment: @EJP Yes you are correct I removed that one. I think my earlier answer still stands as the correct.

Comment: @Ohlaph Do you set permissions for reading from the external storage in the AndroidManifest.xml File

Comment: I did.  The problem I'm having with your code is the null file dir.  I get this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: from where do you call `addCurrentList()` and `record()` methods. add that code also

Comment: From the main activity.

Comment: in your code I do not see record() method get called.

Comment: it currently crashes the app.  If I remove the record() method it launches just fine.  Again, thank you for going into great lengths on this question.  This is my first app and I have a lot to learn.  It seems like reading a textfile would be easy.  I have both input and output working fine in netbeans, but when I transfer the code into the android studio, it just crashes.  Your updated code works, unless I call record.

Comment: Turns out I have to implement Serializable to Item and List.  Thank you!  You went out of your way to help me and for that I am truly thankful!

Comment: @Ohlaph I have been it the same place you are now. That is why :). So, Good luck with Android.

Comment: Thank you!  I have it working now, only thing is when I add item to list, destroy the app, then open it again and try to remove an item, it'll crash.  Still working on that, but it's a very simple grocery list app.  Thought I would make something useful and ad-free.  Thanks again for your help!